# jQuery tools, invalid message, not being removed

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate, jquery-tools

I am using the latest version of jQuery (1.7.1) with the latest  version of jQuery Tools, and it's html5 validator.

What's happening is, when the field has text in it, the error is not being removed. As if it's not valid, but it is.

This is my input:

```
<input type="text" class="text medium" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name*" rel="tip" title="First Name" required="required" data-message="Your first name is required"/>
```

I thought it was something else in the page, but I've doing the bare min, and it's still doing it? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Including the source file from git (https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools) instead of the one from their download page fixed it for some reason.